Factoring out the socle of the projective-injectives for a quiver algebra
Let $A$ be a quiver given in the GAP-package QPA (https://folk.ntnu.no/oyvinso/QPA/) .

Question: Is there a fast/easy way to obtain $A/soc(U)$ (using QPA), where $U$ is the direct sum of all indecomposable projective-injective $A$-modules?

Note that $soc(U)$ is a two-sided ideal.
Here is a way to do it, but it is terrible slow. Maybe someone knows a better way:
projA:=IndecProjectiveModules(A);U:=Filtered(projA,x->IsInjectiveModule(x)=true);UU:=DirectSumOfQPAModules(U);T:=Filtered(projA,x->IsInjectiveModule(x)=false);TT:=DirectSumOfQPAModules(T);RegA:=DirectSumOfQPAModules([UU,TT]);inc:=DirectSumInclusions(RegA);f:=inc[1];O:=Source(f);
g:=SocleOfModuleInclusion(O);h:=g*f;O:=CoKernel(h);B:=EndOfModuleAsQuiverAlgebra(O)[3];


This might be faster:
projA := IndecProjectiveModules( A );
U := Filtered( projA, x -> IsInjectiveModule( x ) = true );
socU := List( U, u -> SocleOfModuleInclusion( u ) );
gensofsoc := [];
for f in socU do 
  bas := BasisVectors( Basis( Source( f ) ) )[ 1 ];
  Add( gensofsoc, ImageElm( f, bas ) );
od;
posU := List( U, u -> Position( projA, u ) );
newrels := List( [1..Length(posU)], i -> ElementInIndecProjective( A, gensofsoc[i],posU[i] ) );
kQ := OriginalPathAlgebra( A );
oldrels := RelationsOfAlgebra( A );
Append( newrels, oldrels );
Amodsoc := kQ / newrels;

The QPA-team

Thank you. I think the line (above the last line) should be Append( newrels, oldrels ); instead of Append( newrels, oldrelations );
Some small experiments suggest that it is indeed much faster!

I have corrected the code as you pointed out. Glad that it hopefully will run faster! QPA-team.
